# First-time setup of maven with netbeans

Tags: java, maven

So I have an existing (see: completed) project that I am trying to turn into a maven based project on Netbeans 7.2 (Which I think comes bundled with Maven 3) and I can't seem to find a helpful guide on the subject.

Does Maven need to be running on a server somewhere or is it client side only?  Do I have to change anything in my subversion to point elsewhere?  Do I need to change anything in properties / etc?

Any help on this would be appreciated since it seems like most Maven guides are not aimed at windows users / people unfamiliar with Maven.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of project are you working on? web app or desktop app? and list the frameworks and libraries you use?

Comment: Have you checked out the netbeans tutorials for maven? They should get you up and running real fast: http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart68.html

Comment: It's a desktop app that uses 1 company-only library, and then others like Jsoup, opencsv, httpclient, httpcore, and HttpAsync client (Apache commons)